# Weak maximization condition

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed convex set and a funtion
$f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I read that the condition 
$$
u \in \arg \max_{v\in \Omega} \; f(v)
$$
can be weakened as
$$
\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(u), y-u \rangle \le 0,\quad \text{for all } y\in \Omega
$$

- If $u\in \overset{\circ}{\Omega}$, then the conditions are equivalent ?
- Also the result comes from the supporting theorem, nothing else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $f$ is differentiable.

Suppose $\langle \nabla f(u), y-u\rangle > 0$ for some $y \in \Omega$. This inner product is the directional derivative $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{f(u+t(y-u))-f(u)}{t}$, so for some small $t$ we have $f(u+t(y-u)) > f(u)$, and thus $u$ is not a maximizer for $f$ in $\Omega$.
Phrased differently, **if $u$ is a maximizer for $f$ in $\Omega$, then $\langle \nabla f(u), y-u\rangle \le 0$ for all $y \in \Omega$.**

If we further assume $f$ is *concave* and twice differentiable, then the converse holds as well.
Suppose $\langle \nabla f(u), y-u\rangle \le 0$ for all $y \in \Omega$. Then for any $z \in \Omega$,
$$f(y) = f(u) + \underbrace{\langle \nabla f(u), y-u\rangle}_{\le 0} + \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\langle\nabla^2f(\xi) (y-u), y-u\rangle}_{\le 0}
\le f(u),$$
where $\xi = u+t(y-u)$ for some $t \in (0,1)$. The gradient term is nonpositive by our assumption, and the Hessian term is nonpositive because concavity of $f$ implies the Hessian is negative semi-definite.
In summary, **if $f$ is concave and $\langle \nabla f(u), y-u\rangle \le 0$ for all $y \in \Omega$, then $u$ is a maximizer for $f$ in $\Omega$.**

---

Response to comment:

$\langle \nabla f(u), y-u\rangle$ is the directional derivative in the direction from $u$ to $y$. Taking $t$ from $1$ to $0$, the point $u+t(y-u)$ varies from $y$ to $u$, and by convexity of $\Omega$ these points all lie in $\Omega$. When I write $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{f(u+t(y-u))-f(u)}{t}$, I am taking $t \to 0$ from above, so $t$ is always positive.

If you take $t < 0$, there is no guarantee that $u+t(y-u)$ lies in $\Omega$ anymore. But if it does, you can just consider a different "$y$" to handle this "negative" direction.

Comment: You could also suppose that $\langle \nabla f(u),y-u\rangle \le 0$ and for small negative we would have $f(u+t(y-u))>f(u)$ and then $u$ is not a maximizer.
The point I don't understand is why the sign of $t$ doesn't play any role ?

Comment: @Smilia This argument does not work because you cannot take $t$ to be a small negative number. See my above edit.

Comment: ok but in that case that $t$ is negative and $u+t(y-u)$ is in $\Omega$ (it seems this case appears when $u$ is in the interior), then even if we consider an other $y$, we have to show that $f(u+t(y-u))<f(u)$ which is not  guaranteed ? Indeed, for many $t<0$, it's possible to have  $f(u+t(y-u))>f(u)$  ? what I am missing ?

Comment: @Smilia I mean that if $u+t(y-u) \in \Omega$ for some $t<0$, then you can consider $y' = u+t(y-u)$ and restart the argument, using the assumption on $\langle \nabla f(u), y'-u \rangle$. In fact, you will see that a variation of the above argument can show that if $u$ is in the interior of $\Omega$, then we must have $\nabla f(u) = 0$, which is the usual condition in an unconstrained minimization.

Comment: ok thanks,  have a nice day!